# Reading from UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, uitextfield

I've got a `UITextField *personIDTextField;` and I want to get data from it. I do it with next code:

```
  NSString* serviceid =   _personIDTextField.text;
NSLog(@"serviceid:", _personIDTextField.text);
```

But I can't get my data. `NSLog` shows just `2014-07-29 10:15:46.538 Nay[2185:11303] serviceid:`

What is wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Actual log is only this `serviceid:` which says you don't have any data in the TextField, do you have, or its blank..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not giving the actual argument to print the `UITextField` data...

Print it like this:

```
NSLog(@"serviceid: %@", _personIDTextField.text);
```

Hope it helps...!!!